# Telerik test automation find last element by class name

Tags: telerik, selenium-webdriver

In my **`specflow`** acceptance test i need to find the last element by given class name, i try to use **`HtmlFindExpression`** but unable to figure out correct expression.

```
            Element element = WebBrowser.CurrentBrowser.WaitForElement(new HTMLFindExpression("class=case-note-text"),5000, true)
            string value = element.InnerText;
            StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("Testing", value, string.Format("abc"));
```

Comment: There's no SpecFlow here, are you using selenium?

Comment: Or Telerik's Test Automation Framework?

Comment: yaa specflow embedded with telerik's ArtOfTest web aii